# PostgreSQL - find matching line in char/string column?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

How can I find matching line in char/string type column?

For example let say I have column called `text` and some row has content of:

```
12345\nabcdf\nXKJKJ
```

(where `\n` are real new lines)

Now I want to find related row if any of lines match. For example, I have value `12345`,
then it should find match. But if I have value `123`, It would not.

I tried using `like` but it finds in both cases, when I have matching value (like `12345`) and partially matching value (like `123`).

For example something like this, but to have boundary for checking whole line:

```
SELECT id
FROM my_table
WHERE text like [SOME_VALUE]
```

**Update**

Maybe its not yet clear what Im asking. But basically I want something equivalent what you can do with regular expression,
like this: https://regexr.com/5akj1

Here regular expression `/^123$/m` would not match my string, it would only match if it would have been with pattern `/^12345$/m` (when I use pattern, value is dynamic, so pattern would change depending what value I got).

Comment: A regular 'equal' would not work for you? `text = '12345'` ?

Comment: Well `12345` is just a line in column value, not whole value. In other words, its `12345\nsomething\nsomethingelse\netc`

Comment: Ok, I thought that every line was a single row. Added an answer, see if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `regexp_replace` and then check that the replaced string is not equal to the original column value:

```
select count(*) 
from dummy 
where regexp_replace(mytext, '(?m)^1234$', '') <> mytext;
```

You have a demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a9e51/2).

Bear in mind that I have used the `(?m)` modifier, which makes `^` and `$` match begin and end of line instead of begin and end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `~` for matching:

```
where mytext ~ '(\n|^)1234(\n|$)'
```

Comment: Maybe a bit nicer regex: `(?n)^12345$'